# Core Data not saving an incremented integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, properties, sprite-kit

I'm making a SpriteKit game and I need to save the player's score using Core Data. I have a property with int value that starts off as being set to "5" and increment it x amount of times. I save it then transition to a different scene and fetch it. It shows up un-incremented with the initial value of "5".

I'm new to Core Data so forgive me if this is a stupid question, but **how can I get Core Data to take the incrementation in to account?**  Or **Is information being lost when I reference the property and how can I prevent this?**

```
    self.score = 5;

    self.score++
```

and then save by calling this method.

AppDelegate.m

```
-(void) createObject {

    Score *scoreEntity = (Score *)[NSEntityDescription
                         insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Score"
                         inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    SpaceshipScene *spaceshipSceneReference = [[SpaceshipScene alloc] init];


    id points = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: spaceshipSceneReference.score];

    scoreEntity.points = points;
    scoreEntity.playerName = @"Joe";


    NSError *error = nil;
    // Saves the managedObjectContext
    if (! [[self managedObjectContext] save:&error] ) {
        NSLog(@"An error! %@", error);
    }
}
```

This is how I call it.

SpaceshipScene.m

```
    AppDelegate *appDelegateReference = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
        [appDelegateReference createObject];
```

I then fetch it in another class/scene using this method

AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)fetchObject {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription  entityForName:@"Score"inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Sort fetched data
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByPoints = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"points" ascending:NO];
    // Put them in an array
    NSArray *sortDescriptor = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortByPoints, nil];

    // Pass the array to the fetch request
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptor];


    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Problem %@", error);
    }

    for (Score *s in fetchedObjects) {
        NSLog(@" %@ %d",s.playerName, [s.points integerValue]);
    }
}
```

This is how I call it in the final scene/class

```
    AppDelegate *appDelegateReference = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    [appDelegateReference fetchObject];
```

Comment: save context after you change the value.

Comment: If I call the "createobject" method after I changed the value will the if statement at the end of the method save the context for me or is this a wrong assumption?    
    if (! [[self managedObjectContext] save:&error] ) {
        NSLog(@"An error! %@", error);
    }

Comment: I don't see you using self.score anywhere.

Comment: You're doing a bunch of things wrong, so I would suggest learning the basics of iOS programming before trying to use core data. In several places you have something like, SpaceshipScene *spaceshipSceneReference = [[SpaceshipScene alloc] init]; or AppDelegate *appDelegateReference = [[AppDelegate alloc] init]; You can't get a reference that way, you're just creating new objects, not getting a reference to the one you already have. Also, you shouldn't be creating a new scoreEntity if you just want to change its value. You need to fetch it, and update its value instead.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out! I've been have a lot of trouble with class referencing. If could you provide with a link or tutorial something that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will work, after fetching your Score entity , simply assign new values in it don't use insert object for update any value.

```
 [scoreEntity setPoints:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: spaceshipSceneReference.score]];
 [scoreEntity setPlayerName:@"Joe"];
```

then Save the values:

```
NSError *error = nil;
// Saves the managedObjectContext
if (! [[self managedObjectContext] save:&error] ) {
    NSLog(@"An error! %@", error);
}
```